# JFrame ActionPerformed on a button takes full time until it finishes the code

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

It's my first time making GUI on java, and I have a small issue that is pretty annoying.

My code looks something like this.

```
private void RunButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){
    richText.append("Starting...");
    try{ something happens here }
    richText.append("Done...");
}
```

The problem is that when I click run button, it waits until it finishes the task and print "Starting..." and "Done..." at the same time. How do I make it print "Starting" first before and print "Done" after?

Comment: 1) Method names should NOT start with an upper case character. Learn by example and follow the conventions used in the JDK API. 2) The frame will only repaint itself once all the code in the method is finished executing. If it is a short task, then the code will execute too fast and you won't see both messages. If you execute a long running task then that task needs to execute on a separate Thread. One way to do that is to use a SwingWorker. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information.

Comment: @camickr 1) This is auto-generated method by NetBeans. I have no access to change the name (it's highlighted in grey). 2) Thanks for the information. I will try implementing Swingworker properly.

Comment: Then you probably also named the variable incorrectly. Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the tutorial for SwingWorker as suggested on the comment, and it worked! It looks something like this.

```
`private class Worker extends SwingWorker<Void, Void>{
    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception{
        try{ things happen here }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void done(){
        try{ get (); } catch (){}
    }
}
```

And to call this, `RunButtonActionPerformed` just needs `new Worker().execute()`.

Answer (score 0):

This code is executed in EDT, so any UI changes (richText.append in your case) will be repainted after it. You should execute your heavy task in new thread.

```
private void RunButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){
    richText.append("Starting...");
    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try{ something happens here }
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                richText.append("Done...");
            });
        }
    }.start();
    
}
```

Or use SwingWorker to get extra functionality such as reporting progress of task completion